# Get the table name / entity of a column

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I would like to check if there is a table in my MySQL database, which has a column called `country`. If so, I would like to know the table name / entity of it.

Is that possible?

Comment: Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/columns-table.html , write query. If you don't have permission get somebody who has to write query,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
show tables from database like 'country';
```

Using like to have the exact match, if your query returns result that means there is a table else there isn't.